# java spark - Why is my Dataset<Row> error?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm using java to make a jar file to run in spark using spark-submit

and in my java project i imported clickhouse-jbdc.jar (Cause my JDBC will be clickhouse based)

and also spark-core, spark-hive, spark-sql (2.12-3.1.1) jar

but when I type

```
        Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
            .format("jdbc")
            .option("url", "jdbc:clickhouse://192.168.0.1:8123")
            .option("dbtable"."test_filter." + args[1])
            .option("user","user")
            .option("password","pass")
            .load();
```

the Row is 'cannot resolve' state

also when I write df.write code

```
df2.write()
            .jdbc("jdbc:clickhouse://192.168.0.1:8123","test,test", connectionProperties);
```

'write' is unsolvable.

I wonder if my spark library (or dependancy) is not working properly?

I'm using Gradle, spring boot

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
```

^ these two imports are not working I want to know why :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see certain issues with the code itself.

Can you fix this and check ?

**While reading:**

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
            .format("jdbc")
            .option("url", "jdbc:clickhouse://192.168.0.1:8123")
            //.option("dbtable"."test_filter." + args[1])
            //the above line is incorrect in your code. please correct it to below one
            .option("dbtable" + "test_filter."+args[1])
            .option("user","user")
            .option("password","pass")
            .load();
```

**While writing:**

You have :
`df2.write.jdbc("jdbc:clickhouse://192.168.0.1:8123","test,test", connectionProperties);`

Correct it to: `df2.write().jdbc("jdbc:clickhouse://192.168.0.1:8123","tablename", connectionProperties);`

**Answering the updated question:**

You are missing more dependencies. I guess you have spark core but you need spark-sql dependency as well that will get you `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame` and `org.apache.spark.sql.Row` classes.

Maven (please look for right version that matches for you):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Gradle (please look for right version that matches for you):

```
compileOnly group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.11', version: '2.4.5'
```

Comment: Thank you, I've corrected those and it's still underlined in red. But this helped me as well ! thank you !

Comment: Updated the answer to fix edited quesiton.

Comment: thank you !! I had no idea in Gradle we had to add the dependancy :O Thank you so much for the help, now its working !